# Can't hide status bar when doing windows.open on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Why status bar is still shown when I'm using window.open("test.html", "a", "status=no"). This doesn't work on IE8 only and only if site is not in trusted zone. In this case status bar appears no matter what I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an IE8 Security feature.

By default, non-trusted sites can't hide window elements (status bar, address bar) when opening new windows.

The idea is to prevent a malicious site from masquerading as a trusted site and hiding the address and status bars so you can't tell the real URL of the page.

Users do have the option of disabling this feature though.

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers don't allow the hiding of the status bar for security reasons. Browsers show the target of a link there in order to avoid things like

```
<a href="http://some.evil.phishing.site">http://your.bank</a>
```