# Remove status bar on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

there is any way to remove status bar from IE8 browsers using javascript or jquery or someting else.

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with your scrollbar? It is a browser thing, your side can't control it (save for very few cases such as when opening popups in some browsers).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299253/cant-hide-status-bar-when-doing-windows-open-on-ie8

Comment: I have few javascript warnings that are displayed on status bar of IE8 and I don't want my client to see that :D

Comment: Why do you want to remove that status bar? IMHO, that's horrible design.

Comment: Why don't you just fix your Javascript errors?

Comment: @Tyler Crompton :))) try to make IE 8 to render css3 after that you could say what you want ;)  that warning is annoying and does not have any impact on my app.

Comment: So you are trying to hide it because of a warning about CSS 3. I'm not *that* familiar with IE, but it sounds like you need to code your application to not use CSS 3 when in IE 8 or less. Look up conditional IE tags (or whatever they call it).

Comment: @Tyler Crompton As I already said  there is a library through which you can make IE8 to render css3 unfortunately sometimes you receive this annoying warnings ... and because of that I need to remove or disable that status bar on IE.

Comment: Just, don't. Users don't like it when you mess around with their stuff. It sounds like you have a faulty library.

Answer (score 3):

The `window.open` method accepts optional arguemnts allowing you to disable the status bar in IE

```
window.open('/yourpage.html','_blank','status=no');
```

(opens yourpage.html in a new window with no status bar)

Note, this will only work in trusted sites.

If your site isn't trusted, the user would have to explicitly enable the

> Allow Websites to open windows without address or status bars

In internet site zone security setting

Comment: Nice option , unfortunately this is not helping me very much :| because I have tabs that are accessed and not a simple page :|  I already used your suggestion and status bar is there in browser with No but still displayed.

Comment: @burebistaruler in that case what you're asking for is impossible without action on the user's side. I'm sorry. If you find a creative solution let me know.

Comment: @burebistaruler I would appreciate if if you did __not__ accept this answer for a while so more users would get the chance to see it. This way if such a way under your constraints _does_ exist (According to the documentation it does not) we'll get a better answer.